# How do i save an arrays in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to store 25 arrays in a 5x5 array in python.

Currently, I am trying to slice an image using openCV into 25 pieces using nested for loops.
I am having difficulty storing the cropped images in the slices array

```
board = cv.imread("King Domino dataset/Cropped and perspective corrected boards/1.jpg",1)

tileDimW = int(board.shape[0]/5)
tileDimH = int(board.shape[1]/5)

slices = np.array([5,5])
slice = np.array([tileDimH,tileDimW])

for h in range(5):
    for w in range(5):
        slice = board[tileDimH*h:tileDimH*(h+1),tileDimW*w:tileDimW*(w+1)]
        slices[h,w] = slice
```

I get the error message:
"IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed" in the final line

Comment: Don't use `slice` keyword as variable name.

Comment: What is the `board.shape`?

Comment: You want the `board` with the shape `(X, Y, ...)` to be divided up into 25 tiles, where each tile has the shape `(X/5, Y/5, ...)` and you want those tiles to end up in a array with the shape `(5, 5, X/5, Y/5, ...)`. Do I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

To address what I am guessing is your actual question (see my comment above).

Assuming your `board` is an array with the shape `(X, Y, ...)`. If you want split that up into 25 tiles shaped `(X/5, Y/5, ...)`, you can simply do the following:

1. Split it into 5 "vertical" tiles once along axis 1 (horizontally or column-wise) giving you an array with the shape `(5, X, Y/5, ...)`, i.e. with each tile having the shape `(X, Y/5, ...)`.
2. Split *that* array into 5 *again* along axis 1, which effectively means splitting each of the 5 tiles along their respective axis 0 (vertically or row-wise). Each of those tiles we got from step 1 will then have the shape `(5, X/5, Y/5, ...)`, meaning each sub-tile will be split into 5 tiles of shape `(X/5, Y/5, ...)`.

Say we have array `a` with the shape `(10, 15)`:

```py
a = np.arange(150).reshape(10, 15)
print(a)
```

```
[[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14]
 [ 15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29]
 [ 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44]
 [ 45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59]
 [ 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74]
 [ 75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89]
 [ 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104]
 [105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119]
 [120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134]
 [135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149]]
```

**Step 1**, using [`numpy.hsplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit), which is equivalent to [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) with `axis=1`:

```py
a1 = np.array(np.hsplit(a, 5))
print(a1)
```

```
[[[  0   1   2]
  [ 15  16  17]
  ...
  [120 121 122]
  [135 136 137]]

 [[  3   4   5]
  [ 18  19  20]
  ...
  [123 124 125]
  [138 139 140]]

 [[  6   7   8]
  [ 21  22  23]
  ...
  [126 127 128]
  [141 142 143]]

 [[  9  10  11]
  [ 24  25  26]
  ...
  [129 130 131]
  [144 145 146]]

 [[ 12  13  14]
  [ 27  28  29]
  ...
  [132 133 134]
  [147 148 149]]]
```

**Step 2**:

```py
a2 = np.array(np.hsplit(a1, 5))
print(a2)
```

```
[[[[  0   1   2]
   [ 15  16  17]]

  ...

  [[ 12  13  14]
   [ 27  28  29]]]


 [[[ 30  31  32]
   [ 45  46  47]]

  ...

  [[ 42  43  44]
   [ 57  58  59]]]

  ...
  ...
  ...

 [[[120 121 122]
   [135 136 137]]

  ...

  [[132 133 134]
   [147 148 149]]]]
```

Thus you can achieve the final result in one line like so:

```py
b = np.array(np.hsplit(np.array(np.hsplit(a, 5)), 5))
print(b.shape)
```

```
(5, 5, 2, 3)
```

Then you have 5 x 5 tiles with the shape `(2, 3)`.

Thus, you should be able to achieve what you want, by doing this:

```py
slices = np.array(np.hsplit(np.array(np.hsplit(board, 5)), 5))
```

Avoid `for`-loops as much as possible, if you are already working with `numpy` arrays. Almost always there is a `numpy`-solution that is orders of magnitude faster (and probably more concise at that).

Hope this helps.

### Original answer:

Given an array `a` with the shape `(25, X, Y, Z, ...)` you can simply [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it to `(5, 5, X, Y, Z, ...)` like this:

```py
a.reshape((5, 5) + a.shape[1:])
```

For example given `a = np.arange(25*2).reshape((25, 2))`, the array looks like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       ...
       [46, 47],
       [48, 49]])
```

And after the reshaping it looks like this:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9]],

        ...

       [[40, 41],
        [42, 43],
        [44, 45],
        [46, 47],
        [48, 49]]])
```

Comment: I would like slices[0,0] to contain one whole x*y array, for example